# Is it possible to set a new route for a plug-in CP section in Craft 3?

Tags: plugin-development, control-panel, craft3

Is it possible to use a custom route for your plugin's CP section, instead of `cpTrigger/plugin-handle`, or to direct `cpTrigger/plugin-handle` to a different template other than `plugin-handle/index.twig`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From your Plugin class, add this code:

```php
use craft\events\RegisterUrlRulesEvent;
use craft\web\UrlManager;
use yii\base\Event;

// ...

class Plugin extends \craft\base\Plugin
{
    $hasCpSection = true;

    public function init()
    {
        // Register a custom CP route
        Event::on(UrlManager::class, UrlManager::EVENT_REGISTER_CP_URL_RULES, function(RegisterUrlRulesEvent $e) {
            $e->rules['your/custom/uri'] = ['template' => 'plugin-handle/index'];
        });
    }

    public function getCpNavItem()
    {
        // Use the default name & icon, but customize the URL
        $navItem = parent::getCpNavItem();
        $navItem['url'] = 'your/custom/uri';
        return $navItem;
    }

    // ...
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Of course you can [Link](https://github.com/craftcms/docs/blob/master/en/updating-plugins.md#registercproutes)

```
Event::on(UrlManager::class, UrlManager::EVENT_REGISTER_CP_URL_RULES, function(RegisterUrlRulesEvent $event) {
    $event->rules['whateveryoulike'] = ['template' => 'cocktails/_edit'];
    $event->rules['cocktails/<widgetId:\d+>'] = 'cocktails/edit-cocktail';
});
```

So the url `www.example.com/admin/whateveryoulike` redirects you to the template `cocktails/_edit`. You don't need to use the plugin-handle, you can overwrite everything but you have to make sure no other plugin overwrites your routes..